# Resolve JSHint's "Don't use 'with'" recommendation

Tags: jquery, jslint, jshint

I am using a script that was written in 2006 and rewriting it so that it follows best practices, and for future inclusion into a side project. I use JSHint.com to figure things out and search SO for solutions to other problems it finds. However, I am unable to resolve JSHint's "Do not use 'with'" error. Here is the code:

```
DragResize.prototype.select = function (newElement) {

    with(this) {
        // Selects an element for dragging.
        if (!document.getElementById || !enabled) return;

        // Activate and record our new dragging element.
        if (newElement && (newElement != element) && enabled) {
            element = newElement;

            // Elevate it and give it resize handles.
            element.style.zIndex = ++zIndex;
            if (this.resizeHandleSet) this.resizeHandleSet(element, true);

            // Record element attributes for mouseMove().
            elmX = parseInt(element.style.left);
            elmY = parseInt(element.style.top);
            elmW = element.offsetWidth;
            elmH = element.offsetHeight;
            if (ondragfocus) this.ondragfocus();
        }
    }

};
```

The only explanation I have managed to find is the one here: http://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-with, but I do not know how to apply it to the above code. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

That code is a brilliant example of why the `with` statement is so horrible to work with! To resolve the JSHint warning you need to know which of the identifiers referred to in the body of the `with` statement are actually properties of the `DragResize` instance (`this`) and which are actually references to variables in outer scopes.

If, for example, `element` is a property of the instance, you need to prefix those references with `this`:

```
DragResize.prototype.select = function (newElement) {

    if (!document.getElementById || !enabled) return;

    if (newElement && (newElement != element) && enabled) {
        this.element = newElement;
//      ^ prefix instance properties with reference to the instance

        this.element.style.zIndex = ++zIndex;
        if (this.resizeHandleSet) this.resizeHandleSet(element, true);

        // ...

    }
};
```

Comment: I have tried this on many other configurations, but nothing's working. There are about 7 more `with(this)` statements too. Should I post a link to the entire script?